# Replace woocommerce attribute label with image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to replace the woocommerce attributes labels with images. The below code works but it does not fetching the image when using the variable $string_utf8 or $imagesurl. It shows an image only if I hardcode a URL like https://image.image on the img src

Can someone help?

```
function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $itcs_image_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $taxonomy = $name;
    
    if( $taxonomy )
        $query = "SELECT guid FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND ID = '$itcs_image_id'";
        $imagesurl = $wpdb->get_var($query);
        $string_utf8 = wp_get_attachment_image_url($itcs_image_id);
        error_log("Taxonomy function " . $taxonomy);
        error_log("Taxonomy product " . $imagesurl);
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 10, 3 );
        $label .= '<div class="custom-label"><img src="'.$string_utf8.'" alt="'. $name .'"></div>'.$name;
        error_log("label: " . $label);
            return $label;
}
```

Comment: On the actual website, right click on the image and inspect element. Review the link in `src` and see if it is the desired path.

Comment: @ConnorLx3 it prints nothing after the img src. It seems like the html code cannot run the php variable and get the value.

Comment: It’s very possible that wp_get_attachment isn’t working correctly. You said when you apply a hard a hard coded value to `string_utf8` it works, that means the error is with that function. You’ll have to debug with echo statements or reviewing the code.

Comment: It's weird because I tried to get the URL value with an sql query too and it did not work too. So, there is no issue with the wp_get_attachment, I was also able to print the URL on the logs.